# File prediction program

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've got an xml configuration file with the following file formats:

```
 <FILE FILEFORMAT="|PREFIX|DATETIME|-|STRING|NUMBER|_|DATETIME2|-|TIME|SUFFIX|" />
 <FILE FILEFORMAT="|PREFIX|NUMBER|_|DATETIME|-|TIME|SUFFIX|" />
 <FILE FILEFORMAT="|DATETIME|_|PREFIX|_|STRING|_|DATETIME2|-|TIME|SUFFIX|" />
 <FILE FILEFORMAT="|PREFIX|_|STRING|_|STRING2|_|DATETIME|_|DATETIME2|-|TIME|SUFFIX|"/>
```

where prefix is only alphabet, datetime/datetime2 is just numbers, not the actual datetime type(I will convert that into datetime later on), string is another alphabet, number is 0 to 9 numbers, time is digits also, suffix is the format of the file like .xml or .txt.

Examples of actual files:

> ```
> `SUXX20111101-BATCH2240_20111113-091322.txt`
> `TOBEME826908_20111113-091413.txt`
> `2011-12-01_MYSELF_ANDI_20111208-121517.txt`
> `WELL_MAYBENOT_TRUE_092011_20111215-022931.txt`
> ```

What I have to accomplish is to check weather the file name is according to specified format or not, there are multiple clients with different formats, I don't know how to go and solve this puzzle, any help is greatly appreciated. basically the idea is not to touch the programming side if more files come in the future, adding their info to config file should suffice.

Comment: Why have you mixed delimited file format with XML?

Comment: @Yuck - I think that is their way of describing how the filenames need to be tokenized.

Comment: If these are supposed to be input masks like @M.Babcock is suggesting you should probably use a RegEx to describe them instead of what you have here.

Comment: "|" is the distinction character between different parts of name

Comment: What regexes have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried any yet due to not being proficient in it, my first instinct is to split the string with "_" or "-".

Comment: Thanks every one for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what exactly you need, however if it's a way to describe your filename pattern, you should simply use Regular Expression.

Then you just have to loop among all formats.

Here is a sample of how to do the search (assuming you have loaded your xml formats in formats, your searching directory in dir)

```
Dictionary<string, Regex> formatDic = new Dictionary<string, Regex>();
foreach(XElement curFormat in formats)
{
     formats.Add(
         curFomat.Attribute("NAME"), 
         new Regex(curFomat.Attribute("FILEFORMAT"), RegexOptions.Compiled));
}

foreach(FileInfo curFile in dir.GetFiles())
{
    try
    {
    Console.WriteLine(
        "File : {0} is of type : {1}",
        curFile.FullName,
        (from c in formatDic
         where c.Value.IsMatch(curFile.FullName)
         select c.Key).Single());
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occuring on file : {0}", curFile.FullName);
    }
}
```

For more information on regexp : [Regular expression on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Comment: building regex for different file formats. (?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)-BATCH\d+_\d+-\d+\.(?:[a-z][a-z]+)   for type  "SUXX20111101-BATCH2240_20111113-091322.txt"

Comment: That's it, however, you should check that your regexp capture only one format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you need the following, at minimum:

- Some way of defining the components of the patterns (i.e. `DATETIME`, etc.)
- Some way of defining how to validate those components (i.e. so that "20110956" isn't considered a valid date.
- Some way of defining the patterns that you want to recognize (i.e. parsing the individual components from the strings).

You *might* be able to do the first and the third with regular expressions. You can't, in the general case, do the second. If you add a new type of component, you'll have to write code to validate it.

What it looks like you're trying to build is, at its simplest, a regular expression builder that can combine regexes for the different components into a single regex that defines a particular pattern. What you're really building is a parser generator, and I question your need to do that.

You also have to be very careful of ambiguity. For example, imagine you have these two formats:

```
PREFIX|DATETIME|-|NUMBER|SUFFIX
PREFIX|NUMBER|-|DATETIME|SUFFIX
```

Since it looks like your `DATETIME` can be of the form `20110315`, it could easily be construed as a number. For example, given:

```
xyz20110315-20041231.txt
```

Which is the date and which is the number?

I don't see any obvious problems in the patterns that you've shown, but I can easily envision running into problems in the future when you want to add a new format. You *will* encounter conflicts.

Also, if your number of regular expressions grows very large, checking a large number of incoming files against all those regular expressions is going to be very, very expensive.

In my opinion, the benefit of having such a generalized file name categorization scheme will  never be worth the time you spend building and maintaining it. Because it *will* need maintenance. In fact, you'll probably find yourself tweaking it every time you get a new customer.

So just write the simplest thing you can. Do it in code, and resign yourself to modifying it whenever you get a new file type.

Comment: I have already coded the whole program but the higher management wants an XML implementation, I guess they were annoyed by too many switch case statements.